# Unwanted animation on navigation bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a customized back button in my navigation bar.
When the keybord appear I just replace the back button with a close button.
When the keyboard is closed, I restore the back button.

Here is the function I use to set the left navigation button :

```
-(UIBarButtonItem*)configureLeftButtonWithImageName:(NSString*)imageName
                                         target:(id)target
                                         action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *accountButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [accountButton setImage:buttImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    float padding = 4;

    accountButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(padding, 0, padding, 2*padding);
    float buttH = kNavigationButtonHeight + 2*padding;
    float buttW = buttH;
    if( buttImage )
    {
        buttW = buttH * buttImage.size.width / buttImage.size.height;
    }
    accountButton.bounds = CGRectMake(padding, padding, buttW, buttH);

    [accountButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:accountButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
    return barButtonItem;
}
```

And here where I switch :

```
-(void)kbDidAppear
{
    [self configureLeftButtonWithImageName:@"quit" target:self action:@selector(hideKb:)];
}

-(void)kbDidDisappear
{
    [self configureLeftButtonWithImageName:@"back" target:self action:@selector(navigationBack:)];
}
```

But when the back button is replaced with the quit button, an unwanted animation is played :

The quit button appeared offseted to the top left corner of the navigation bar, the position is then animated to its normal values ...

When I switch from quit button to back button, the problem does not appear !

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a workaround, I was switching from *back* button to *quit* button in the 
**UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** callback, if I do it in **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification** callback, no more weird animation